# list index out of range when visualizing decision tree

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have been trying to visualize my decision tree, however, I get the following error: IndexError: list index out of range.

I am quite new to this field and I can't seem to find the source of the error.
For the visualization, I used the following libraries

```
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
from IPython.display import Image  
import pydotplus
```

Below is part of the code I used:

```
#select features (independent variables) and target (dependent variable)
feature_columns = df.columns[80:137]
feature_columns = feature_columns.drop(['Gehaald'])
X = df[feature_columns] 
Y = df.Gehaald

# 70% training and 30% test
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0) 

# Create Decision Tree classifer object
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()

# Train Decision Tree Classifer
clf = clf.fit(X_train,Y_train)

#Predict the response for test dataset
Y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

# Model Accuracy, how often is the classifier correct?
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(Y_test, Y_pred))

print(df['Gehaald'].unique())
#answer: [1,2]

dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data,  
                filled=True, rounded=True,
                special_characters=True,feature_names = feature_columns,class_names= ['1','2'])
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
graph.write_png('escaperoom.png')
Image(graph.create_png())
```

The complete error is:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-329-43f2d5a7fb58> in <module>()
      4 export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data,  
      5                 filled=True, rounded=True,
----> 6                 special_characters=True,feature_names = feature_columns,class_names= ['1','2'] )
      7 graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
      8 graph.write_png('escaperoom.png')

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/tree/_export.py in node_to_str(self, tree, node_id, criterion)
    335                 node_string += 'class = '
    336             if self.class_names is not True:
--> 337                 class_name = self.class_names[np.argmax(value)]
    338             else:
    339                 class_name = "y%s%s%s" % (characters[1],

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Update: When I change `clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()` into `clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 2, random_state = 0)` the error goes away. Why is this?

Hope anyone is able to give me some clarity. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is `export_graphviz` defined? That's the source of the error.

Comment: This library was already imported, I edited my question to show this.